# Problem migrating contract using truffle. Unknow account message

Tags: truffle, rinkeby

I am trying to migrate a contract using truffle but I get a "Unknown account" message eventhough I tried various ways to unlock the account beforehand. Am I missing something? Any help really appreciated.

Here is the error log :

```
truffle migrate —network rinkeby
Compiling ./contracts/first.sol...
Writing artifacts to ./build/contracts

Using network 'rinkeby'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  ... undefined
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: unknown account
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:37312:16)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:220420:36
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:72910:11
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:204149:9
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:205574:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:73069:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:73359:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:73514:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:73474:24)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
```

Comment: Did you set a 'from' address is your `truffle.js` configuration file? Which other networks have you configured? Do they also fail?